# Retrieve Emails from Office365 (EWS) via OAuth2

Tags: c#, office365, exchangewebservices

Trying to retrieve emails from Office365 via EWS using the following snippet (thanks to emailarchitect) .

After creating the Settings required on Azure Portal ( App Registration, API Permission )... Im able to make it work.

However, I am wondering if we can restrict access to only one mailbox due to privacy concerns as this snippet will allow changing the "mailboxUser" to any other valid mailbox on Office365 from the same domain and it will still be able to retrieve emails.

In other words, if I substitute the mailboxUser = ceo@mydomain.com - the app will retrieve emails to the ceo which we do not want.

I have only Office 365 Exchange Online with 2 API Permission:

- full_access_as_app
- IMAP.AccessAsApp

Where do I specify that the App can only retrieve emails from genericMailbox@mydomain.com ?

Note: I've tried to create a specific permission but it didnt do any difference , when i change the mailbox , it still retrieved mails from a private mailbox.

`Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "genericMailbox@mydomain.com" -User "##replace_with_app_objectid##" -AccessRights FullAccess`

```
       static void RetrieveEmail()
    {
        try
        {
            string client_id = "##replace_with_client_id##";
            string client_secret = "##replace_with_client_secret##";
            string tenant = "##replace_with_tenant##";

            string requestData =
                string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&scope=https://outlook.office365.com/.default&grant_type=client_credentials",
                    client_id, client_secret);

            string tokenUri = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", tenant);
            string responseText = _postString(tokenUri, requestData);

            OAuthResponseParser parser = new OAuthResponseParser();
            parser.Load(responseText);

            //Any email I use here seems to allow retrieval to any hosted mailbox *@mydomain.com  
            // privacy concerns - 
            //How can i ensure that this App cannot access anything EXCEPT genericMailbox@mydomain.com 

            string mailboxUser= "genericMailbox@mydomain.com"; 



            // Create a folder named "inbox" under current directory
            // to save the email retrieved.
            string localInbox = string.Format("{0}\\inbox", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            // If the folder is not existed, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(localInbox))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(localInbox);
            }

            // Office 365 server address
            MailServer oServer = new MailServer("outlook.office365.com",
                    mailboxUser,
                    parser.AccessToken, // use access token as password
                    ServerProtocol.ExchangeEWS); // use Http EWS protocol

            // Set OAUTH 2.0
            oServer.AuthType = ServerAuthType.AuthXOAUTH2;
            // Enable SSL/TLS connection
            oServer.SSLConnection = true;

            MailClient oClient = new MailClient("TryIt");

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting {0} ...", oServer.Server);
            oClient.Connect(oServer);

            MailInfo[] infos = oClient.GetMailInfos();
            Console.WriteLine("Total {0} email(s)\r\n", infos.Length);

            //Max 10 email for POC
            bool maxReached = false;
            for (int i = 0; (i < infos.Length && !(maxReached)); i++)
            {
                MailInfo info = infos[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}; Size: {1}; UIDL: {2}",
                    info.Index, info.Size, info.UIDL);

                // Receive email from email server
                Mail oMail = oClient.GetMail(info);

                Console.WriteLine("From: {0}", oMail.From.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Subject: {0}\r\n", oMail.Subject);

                // Generate an unqiue email file name based on date time.
                string fileName = _generateFileName(i + 1);
                string fullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", localInbox, fileName);

                //// Save email to local disk
                //oMail.SaveAs(fullPath, true);

                //// Mark email as read to prevent retrieving this email again.
                //oClient.MarkAsRead(info, true);

                maxReached = i >= 10;
            }

            // Quit and expunge emails marked as deleted from server.
            oClient.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
        }
        catch (Exception ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ep.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict a Client credentials app to only one mailbox you need to use Application policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access

Unless you really tied to using it then EWS (or IMAP) these aren't the best method of getting email from Office 365 as they are both legacy protocols which maybe restricted in the future (they also don't support the more restrictive permission models). If you want to future proof your code look at using the Graph API instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.